# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertImage
@PCImage varbinary(max)
As
Begin

INSERT INTO dbo.PCInfo PCImage) 
VALUES (@PCImage) 

End
```

When I Write

```
EXEC uspInsertPC 'D:\Desktop.jpg'
```

Showing Error

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: Are you trying to insert the actual file into the database?

Comment: Why is the parameter declared as `varbinary(max)` if you are just passing a string to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tried to save a string into a binary column that’s why you are getting this error

You should tell SQL server to use a different source provider by using OPENROWSET

you should do something the below:

```
INSERT INTO BLOBTest
    (BLOBName, BLOBData)
    SELECT 'First test file', 
        BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(
            Bulk 'C:\temp\nextup.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

For more info have a look at the below:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3724556/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-2.htm

Comment: +1 But @Yogesh if this is what you are attempting to do the file paths need to be from the server's POV not your machine's (if different)